# How do I pass parameters to the URL?

Tags: path-aliases

I want to pass parameters to the URL. With node/1/param1/param2, it works. If node/1 has the contenu/accueil path alias, contenu/accueil/param1/param2 returns a 404 error.

How do I pass parameters to the URL even when there is a path alias defined for the URL?

The Pathauto module is disabled.

Answer (score 3):

You need the [Sub-pathauto (Sub-path URL Aliases)](https://www.drupal.org/project/subpathauto) module for that. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> The Drupal Path module matches only full URLs when creating SEO-friendly aliases. This module extends that behavior by also matching known sub-paths and replacing them with their respective alias.
>
> For example, if user/1 is aliased to users/admin, this module rewrites the link to the user contact page user/1/contact to use the aliased URL users/admin/contact instead. This also includes Views URLs taking a node as argument (e.g. node/%/yourview), in short, every URL that is based on, or extends, an existing alias. In combination with the [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) module it is possible to get rid of all remaining exposed internal non-administrative URLs.